# ASP.NET MVC Dropdownlist + save selectedvalue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to load a dropdownlist with values received from my mysql database.

This is what I have in my **ViewModel**:

```
public int ProjectID { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Projects { get; set; }
```

Create function in my **Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Create(DeliverableViewModel model)
    {
        var projects = (repository.GetProjects()).ToList();
        ViewBag.Projects = projects;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {

                repository.AddDeliverable(model.ProjectID);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ae.Message);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I load the projects in my repository. (values: project_id and project_name)

This is my Create **View**:

```
    @model GDMfrontEnd.Models.DeliverableViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Deliverable", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="editor-field">
                 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Projects,
       new SelectList(ViewBag.Projects,
        "project_id", "project_name"))
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>

    }
```

But now, how can I give my ProjectID from the selected value to my repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming:

```
class DeliverableViewModel 
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

It should be like that:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectID,
    new SelectList(Model.Projects, "project_id", "project_name", Model.ProjectID))
```

You can omit last `Model.ProjectID` if you don't initialize this field, but you will probably use it in edit.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `model=>model.ProjectID` to retrieve selected ProjectID in POST action.

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectID,
           new SelectList(ViewBag.Projects,
            "project_id", "project_name"))
```